# Web driver timeouts when trying to upload large file

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, wait

I am currently working on a Test Script where I am required to upload to files and check if the file upload is successful. I am able to successfully upload the first file as its relatively a very small file (7KB).

However, When I try uploading the second file which is relatively larger (8 MB) for the test environment. The Code times out without continuing with the next step.

I tried using wait statement which is not helping to solve the issue

```
WebElement filePath2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='wrapper']/table[2]/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/ tr[4]/td[2]/form/input[6]"));  

filePath2.sendKeys("\\\\this\\is\\a\\sample\\file\\path\\SAMPLEFILE_LARGE.txt");

driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='wrapper']/table[2]/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]/form/input[7]")).click();

//Used below waits separaytly, but did not work out  

//Thread.sleep(300000);
WebDriverWait wait1 = new WebDriverWait(driver,300 );

boolean upload = driver.getPageSource().contains("SAMPLE FILE LARGE");
if (upload == true){
    System.out.println("Large file uploaded successfully");
}
else{
    System.out.println("Large file DID NOT upload successfully, Exiting automation now.");
}
```

Comment: What happens after the file is uploaded, does the file name appear anywhere, or any other indication that the file was uploaded successfully?

Comment: If you upload the large file manually, how much time does it tooks?

Comment: what is the error/exception you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Thread.sleep(50000);` to wait 50  second or your approximate for next process

Comment: I waited for for Thread.sleep(300000); for 5 minutes, but still errors out

Comment: basally how much time needed complete uploading?

Comment: When I tried running the script manually, It took 4 Minutes and 30 seconds. I am able to manually upload the file consistently. However, even after waiting for 5 minutes, the program times out.

Comment: Thread.sleep(600000); or use  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3600, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

Comment: 1 - your code  is not representative. it is missing the part where uploade process is coded. 2 - I am not sure wait or sleep will help here since it just stops your thread execution, thus the uploading might also be stopped if it is performed in the same thread.